# __stop_SECTION contains wrong value after compilation

Tags: gcc, linker, mcu

While developing code for STM32 MCU, I'm placing some structures into custom memory section:

```
struct MyStruct structName;

__attribute__((__section__("my_section"))) __attribute__((__used__)) const struct MyStruct *const mystruct1 = &x
```

Linker generated additional symbols, `__start_my_section_` and `__stop_my_section_`.
After compilation while debugging MCU, I see that `__start_my_section_` contains a valid value, e.g. 0x20000468 but `__stop_my_section_` is incorrect, equal to 0.

In the .map file, the `__stop_my_section_` also contains a valid value:

```
                0x20000470                __stop_my_section_ = .
```

What's wrong? I haven't added anything to linker script, linker automatically created that section and placed in bss.

Comment: `mystruct1 = &x` you need to show that the load address is in the flash and run address in ram. Then you need to write some startup code to initialize this variable.

Comment: `contains a valid value` How do you check it? `__stop_my_section_` It's not `__stop_my_section_` it's `__stop_my_section`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Address Operator (&) to get the start and stop address of "my_section": `&__start_my_section` and  `&__stop_my_section` respectively